# Why isn't my database updating in entity framework? Just want seed data to go through

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I can't figure out why my database isn't updating. It keeps showing old data like "user1" = mike but "user2" = unknown instead of Tim. All I am trying to do is get data seeded into the DB, nothing extra.

Thanks

```
namespace DatabaseDesign.DAL
{
public class PrivateMessageInitializer :  System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways<PrivateMessageContext> //DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<PrivateMessageContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(PrivateMessageContext context)
    {

        var PrivateMessageHistory = new PrivateMessageHeader();
        var msgItems =  new PrivateMessageDetail { FromUser="mike", MessageDate = DateTime.Now, Message="message 1", PrivateMessageDetailId = 1, PrivateMessageHeaderId = 1 };
        var msgItems2 = new PrivateMessageDetail { FromUser="mike", MessageDate = DateTime.Now, Message="message 2", PrivateMessageDetailId = 2, PrivateMessageHeaderId = 1 };
        var msgItems3 = new PrivateMessageDetail { FromUser="mike", MessageDate = DateTime.Now, Message="message 3", PrivateMessageDetailId = 3, PrivateMessageHeaderId = 1 };
        var msgItems4 = new PrivateMessageDetail { FromUser="mike", MessageDate = DateTime.Now, Message="message 4", PrivateMessageDetailId = 4, PrivateMessageHeaderId = 1 };
        var msgItems5 = new PrivateMessageDetail { FromUser = "mike", MessageDate = DateTime.Now, Message = "message 5", PrivateMessageDetailId = 5, PrivateMessageHeaderId = 1 };
        PrivateMessageHistory.Messages.Add( msgItems );
        PrivateMessageHistory.Messages.Add(msgItems2);
        PrivateMessageHistory.Messages.Add(msgItems3);
        PrivateMessageHistory.Messages.Add(msgItems4);
        PrivateMessageHistory.Messages.Add(msgItems5);

        context.PrivateMessageHeader.Add(PrivateMessageHistory);

        context.SaveChanges();

    }
}
}

public class PrivateMessageContext : DbContext
{
    public PrivateMessageContext()
        : base("PrivateMessageContext")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<PrivateMessageHeader> PrivateMessageHeader { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PrivateMessageDetail> PrivateMessageDetail { get; set; }


}

namespace DatabaseDesign.Models
{
public class PrivateMessageHeader
{
    public int PrivateMessageHeaderId { get; set; }
    public PrivateMessageHeader() { this.Messages = new List<PrivateMessageDetail>();  }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; } // Date of the start of thread
    public string User1 { get; set; }
    public string User2 { get; set; }  // this could be made to a list to allow multiples

    public int numberOfMessages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PrivateMessageDetail> Messages { get; set; }
}
}

namespace DatabaseDesign.Models
{
public class PrivateMessageDetail
{
    public int PrivateMessageDetailId { get; set; }
    public DateTime MessageDate { get; set; }
    public string FromUser { get; set; } // Don't need ToUser, it's already in header
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public int PrivateMessageHeaderId { get; set; }
    public virtual PrivateMessageHeader PrivateMessageHeader { get; set; }
}
}

namespace DatabaseDesign.DAL
{
public class PrivateMessageContext : DbContext
{
    public PrivateMessageContext()
        : base("PrivateMessageContext")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<PrivateMessageHeader> PrivateMessageHeader { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PrivateMessageDetail> PrivateMessageDetail { get; set; }     
}
}
```

web.config:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="PrivateMessageContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=PrivateMessageContext1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

and

```
<entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="DatabaseDesign.DAL.PrivateMessageContext, DatabaseDesign">
        <databaseInitializer type="DatabaseDesign.DAL.PrivateMessageInitializer, DatabaseDesign" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
      </entityFramework>
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with your EF setup; what's more important to show is the actual code that you are running that's causing the problem... these issues are either the EF context has the object cached, and it needs to be refreshed with the Refresh() method, or maybe the object isn't updating correctly because SaveChanges() isn't called, or something like that.

Comment: You basically had it. I wasnt actually calling the controller to make any db changes :D *idiot* ah well, onto my next question...

Comment: note* I'm calling myself an idiot ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the DB to be able to make any changes. I assumed this was on startup, but infact you must call something such as a controller to initiate the DB code.

```
public class PrivateMessageController : Controller
{
    private PrivateMessageContext db = new PrivateMessageContext();

    // GET: /PrivateMessage/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var privatemessagedetail = db.PrivateMessageDetail.FirstOrDefault < PrivateMessageDetail>();
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DbContext should be as follows

```
public class PrivateMessageContext : DbContext
{
    public PrivateMessageContext()
        : base("PrivateMessageContext")
    {
       Database.SetInitializer( new PrivateMessageInitializer<PrivateMessageContext>());

    }
    public DbSet<PrivateMessageHeader> PrivateMessageHeader { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PrivateMessageDetail> PrivateMessageDetail { get; set; }


}
```